# How to deploy Windows 8.0 app on Windows 8.1 tablet?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I have Windows RT tablet with 8.1 update. I'm trying to build both 8.0 and 8.1 versions of my app. I have no problem deploy my app from Visual Studio 2013 (windows 8.1 version) onto the device. But when I try to deploy the app from Visual Studio 2012 (windows 8.0 version), it says:

```
Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named 'tablet:4018'.  The remote debugger is not an acceptable version.
```

Remote Tools 2012 refuse to run on the 8.1 tablet, it says the .dll signature are not compatible, or so.

Comment: Install the 2012 remote debugger tools on the tablet. They can be installed side by side with the 2013 tools.

Comment: I downloaded latest update for Remote Tools 2012 and it didn't work. I had to remove all the remote tools and install them again, now they work. Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the 2012 Remote Debugger Tools on the tablet. Afterwards, you can install the 2013 version side by side as well.